# Migrating Connected App , Auth. Provider and Named Credential

Tags: oauth2, ant, connected-apps, migration, package.xml

I have recently implemented Oauth authentication for one of the integration in my Salesforce Dev org. I have different env in the project- Dev,SIT,QA,Prod.

I want to migrate the configuration - Connected App , Auth. Provider and Named Credential from one env to another using ant migration tool. Is it possible? Or do I have to create it again in each environment that I migrate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ConnectedApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm), [AuthProvider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_authproviders.htm) and [NamedCredential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_namedcredential.htm) are supported types to deploy by means migration tool.
So answer is: yes, it is possible to migrate named upper metadata by means of ant migration tool.

Check all supported types in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm)